# FTP Recursive...how to skip it if I already have the file?

Tags: perl

I am using [Net::FTP::Recursive](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Net-FTP-Recursive/) to download all of the files on my server to localhost on a daily basis. Is there a way to check for file existence on localhost b/f I download everything? I'd like to skip the files I already have downloaded.

```
my $host = "host"; my $user = "u"; my $password = "p";
my$f = Net::FTP::Recursive->new($host, Debug => 0, Passive => 0);
    $f->login($user,$password);
    $f->rget();    
    $f->quit;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you could do is, before you initialize your FTP connection, get a list of files that are on your local machine. Then bodge these together into a regex, and use the `OmitFiles` property of `rget` to omit the files on your local machine.

Of course, this doesn't handle the case where a file has been modified on the remote machine and you don't have that modification. Or the case where your transfer got interrupted and you only have half a file.

You should probably think about using `rsync` instead, whether that's using the command-line program or the [`File::Rsync` module](http://search.cpan.org/dist/File-Rsync/).

Answer (score 4):

The `rget` method in `Net::FTP::Recursive` takes a `ParseSub => sub { ... }` argument that decides which files on the remote server should be retrieved.

Take a look at the `parse_files` method in [the source code](http://cpansearch.perl.org/src/JDLEE/Net-FTP-Recursive-2.04/Recursive.pm) -- that is the default function that `rget` uses -- and see how you can use a modified version of it to exclude files that already exist on your local host.

Comment: thanks. None of them seem to have something that checks if the file exists on localhost...it's just performs regex on the remotehost

Comment: Right, you have to implement your own `my_parse_files` routine that checks your local host for the files.